# Navbar on specific page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ejs

In my blog website, I have a navbar. It appears on every page (landing page, particular article page etc). But I only want it to  appear on certain specific pages.

The problem is that I have my header and footer part in different ejs (templating engine) files ( header.ejs and footer.ejs) and included it on other pages in this way:

```
<% include partials/header %>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

If I remove the navbar from a certain specific page, I'll have to write the entire header part specifically for that page. How can I maintain navbar for only certain pages without writing DRY code ?

Comment: Have you tried removing it through writing css code? Such as display:none; ?

Comment: display:none will probably remove the navbar for all pages, I want it removed for a specific page(s).

Comment: No it won't, you can specify the id of that page. Like in wordpress we do it like this, #page-id-325 navbar{display:none;} It will remove navbar from specific page only.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using Wordpress, so I don't know about this. Could you tell me how to use this? How do we assign an id to a **page** ?

Comment: just go to the body/header tag of the page(depending where the navbar exists) that you want to target and give it any Id. Such as <body/header id="homepage"> then you can write in css this code  #homepage .navbar{display:none;}